# Corrupted iPhone app download results in no sound?

Tags: iphone, debugging, itunes, corruption

I have an iPhone app in the iTunes store.  Roughly 0.1% of the people who download it complain that the app has no sound.  They report that their phone is not muted and that other apps have sound.

I have asked these people to delete my app and download it again.  This fixes the problem -- after re-downloading, my app has sound.

It's certainly possible that my program has an odd bug, but I'm wondering if slightly corrupted app downloads are possible.  Has anybody heard of this?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible. Before begin able to run, all apps are checked to make sure the binary hasn't been altered. If one byte is different it won't run. That's one thing that makes pirating apps more difficult on iPhone.